# Tensorflow object detection resource exhaustion OOM exception

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying out the tensorflow object detection apis and I was able to successfully fine tune the faster_rcnn_resnet101 and exported a inference file.

However I am getting the below error while trying to detect image using my model.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ec0c1510b78c> in <module>()
     30       (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
     31           [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
---> 32           feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
     33       print(" classes = "+str(classes)+" scores = "+str(scores)+" num# = "+str(num_detections))
     34       print ("vizualizing boxes")

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    787     try:
    788       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 789                          run_metadata_ptr)
    790       if run_metadata:
    791         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    995     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    996       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 997                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    998     else:
    999       results = []

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1130     if handle is None:
   1131       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1132                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1133     else:
   1134       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1150         except KeyError:
   1151           pass
-> 1152       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1153 
   1154   def _extend_graph(self):

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[300,14,14,1024]
     [[Node: CropAndResize = CropAndResize[T=DT_FLOAT, extrapolation_value=0, method="bilinear", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_23/bottleneck_v1/Relu, Reshape_7, Reshape_8/_95, CropAndResize/crop_size)]]
     [[Node: SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Concatenate/concat_3/_151 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_2971_SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Concatenate/concat_3", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](^_cloopSecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/strided_slice/stack_2/_6)]]

Caused by op u'CropAndResize', defined at:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 653, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 162, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-57652895f483>", line 7, in <module>
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 311, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[300,14,14,1024]
     [[Node: CropAndResize = CropAndResize[T=DT_FLOAT, extrapolation_value=0, method="bilinear", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_23/bottleneck_v1/Relu, Reshape_7, Reshape_8/_95, CropAndResize/crop_size)]]
     [[Node: SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Concatenate/concat_3/_151 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_2971_SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Concatenate/concat_3", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](^_cloopSecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/strided_slice/stack_2/_6)]]
```

below is my tf code that gathers images from test_images and tries to run it.
I dont think its a memory issue because, I am using a high config aws gpu server. 
Also, my test images are small in size 400x400.

```
tfconfig = tf.ConfigProto()
tfconfig.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC'
tfconfig.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.40
tfconfig.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph,config=tfconfig) as sess:
    for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
      image = Image.open(image_path)
      # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
      # result image with boxes and labels on it.
      print("about to convert image ="+image_path+" into np")
      image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      print ("expanding np ...")    
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      print(image_np.shape)
      print ("getting image tensor ...")
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      print ("detecting boxes ...")
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      print ("getting scores, classes and num of detections ...")
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')    
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      print ("building boxes")
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem,  even though i had enough CPU memory, I had to clear my gpu memory by killing the processes running under it (thanks to quora https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-kill-all-the-computer-processes-shown-in-nvidia-smi)

```
(tfpy27) ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-9:~/Object-Detector-App/object_detection$ nvidia-smi 
Sun Dec 10 12:29:04 2017                                                       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 0000:00:1E.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   67C    P0    60W / 149W |   4483MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      8200    C   /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/bin/python             4481MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+  

sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

but still not sure why it was taking up so much memory for running a session on just a single medium sized image